# Wating cursor is not working in IE 11 for Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript

I have an application in which when i click on Grid list the information about that data is elaborated in that page so when i click the grid my watting cursor is not working i have made the function in javascript that create a div and append that control to document and then apply the cursor

Control.setCapture();
Control.style.cursor="wait";
then in next method i release the capture waiting cursor is working fine till IE10 but not in IE 11 can any one help in this regard?

Same goes with when i check any check box and page get post back then also my waiting cursor not working?

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/E6uUQ/, can you provide a demo of your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: you have done it on a simple div i am asking on the controls where __dopostback occur